# Android webview geo: and tel: links

Tags: android, webview, geo, tel

I made android web app which uses WebView. The problem is when I press the geo: or tel: links it stops working. I tried a lot of tips from here, but non of them actualy work.

**XML layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
}

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

**MyAppWebViewClient.java**

```
package com.cromedia.zadarguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by Ivan on 27.02.14..
 */
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example.com")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    }

}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I'm pretty new to this, and I took this instructions to make the app https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted

**So, can anybody try to fill what is missing to make it to not crash when geo: or tel: link is pressed and handle the geo: and tel: links like in chrome?**

**I found the answer!!!**

I replaced this code in MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example.com")) {
    return false;
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
return true;

}

}
```

with this one

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost() != null && Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("domain.com")) 
{
        return false;
    }

    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Might just be your emulator doesnt have any applications to handle `ACTION_VIEW` with that Uri. Check your log it will tell you

Comment: The same problem here ;) I create a app with cordova

Comment: Please add your update as an answer here and mark it as 'solved'.